# Can't import the py-translate 1.03 package

Tags: python, import, package

Is someone familiar with these package?
I tried easy install and many things I saw in imports problems solution

```
>>> import translate
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import translate
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\translate\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .translator import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\translate\translator.py", line 13, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Moreover, in the directory of the package there is a test file.
I tried to run it but I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\translate\tests\test_translator.py", line 10, in <module>
from ..translator import translator
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Answer (score 0):

How have you installed py-translate.
It requires: `requests`

My advice is `pip install requests` (or `easy_install requests`)

Their latest release is 1.0.2, but also goes by 1.0.3.

Pip install the package, don't just download the archive as you will miss the dependancies

Comment: Thx 
I just missed a package.

Comment: But how can I know which package included in the archive I need?

Comment: If your using pip or easy_install, the dependancies are done for you.

Comment: If you install the package by hand, check the setup.py file, it is listed in the requirements.